# How to Oracle ON LOGON trigger impact on performance?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I've created trigger for logon event as showed below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "log_users_session"
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
WHEN USER = 'SomeUser'
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO "users_logon_log" ("username","date") VALUES ("Some user",sysdate)
END;
```

It's big report database. I want to know, is this really slow down database perfomarnce, or has side effects?

My Oracle version 19c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few objections, if I may.

Get rid of double quotes when working with Oracle, i.e. no `"log_users_session"` but `log_users_session`. In Oracle, everything is (by default) stored into data dictionary as uppercase, but you can reference it any way you want. With double quotes, you MUST reference it using exactly that letter case along with double quotes, always.

That affects column name: `"date"`. When you remove double quotes, you'd get `date` and that's an invalid name as `date` is reserved for Oracle datatype; so, use `log_date` or something like that.

As of your question: you decided to log **only** `SomeUser` so - if that user doesn't establish *zillion* connections, I wouldn't expect significant impact. Though, if it is a big reporting database and all users (read: people) use the same credentials while connecting/establishing a new session, then *maybe*. On the other hand, what's the purpose of such a setup? You'd get a large number of connections for the same user for the whole time you monitor that.

Basically, it just depends on what you do and how. It wouldn't cost much if you *try it* and see how it behaves. If it affects performance, don't use it any longer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. In my company, we can't realize full audit of all database (origin purpose) due to limit resources, so we only can try to implement some base audit. I understand that this is not good solution, but...
And this user  used only by some people (access granted only them).

PS. I forgot to say, that log table will contain username like in Active Directory, user host, and ip. And this information, I think, will bу enough for basic audit.

Comment: The trigger is going to fire on _every_ connection, regardless of the user.  It is going to evaluate the 'if' for every connection. I fail to see how this is perceived to be better than using AUDIT for exactly what it was designed _and optimized_ for.  Auditing is not an all-or-nothing proposition. You can configure it to log _only_ connections, just like your trigger. And it will capture all of the data elements you mention. And you won't have to come back and modify it when the list of users in your proposed trigger changes.

Comment: Also, and very importantly, your trigger will only capture successful logins. It won't see failed logins because only a successful login can cause the trigger to fire. Auditing will capture both, which is important for any serious security configuration.

Comment: @KiazimKhutaba Use this instead to only fire for a specific user: `create or replace trigger log_users_session after logon on someuser.schema ...`. That change is important not just for performance, but because if that trigger ever breaks it will at least not break for *everyone*. Also, unless something is seriously wrong with your database, I can't imagine such a simple trigger causing performance problems. Compared to the amount of time needed to create session data, that trigger is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a performance hit ranging from very minimal to significantly high based on the concurrent connections. The hit is linearly proportional to the no. of concurrent connections i.e. More connections mean big hit, less connections mean less hit. It would be ideal to make a decision depending upon the avg no. of users who connects to the system at a given time. I had implemented this for a 300GB database with ~200 connections, it didn't have much impact.

Also, `users_logon_log` table should be taken into account for regular maintenance/clean up from growing too large and occupy significant disk space.

Comment: Hi, thank for your comment! For 200 concurrent connections?

Comment: yes (via scheduled jobs). But the only way to figure out whether your system will handle or not is by trying out.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to record connexions to database, I would simply use database audit features: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/introduction-to-auditing.html#GUID-F901756D-F747-489C-ACDE-9DBFDD388D3E